# 11-vertex graph with nonplanar complement

Tags: graph-theory

I have a 11-vertex planar graph. How do I prove that its complement is nonplanar? The complement is the complete graph minus the original graph.

Comment: Do you know any theorems about planar or non-planar graphs?

Comment: Well I know that a planar graph with at least 4 vertices has at least 4 vertices with degree at most 5. I found that out in another math stack exchange post.

Comment: There are more ideas at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph